# <mat-select> not working properly in MS teams tab in Android

Tags: html, css, angular, microsoft-teams

I had built MS teams tab in Angular using angular material all over, but as seen below the dropdown is showing some unusual working.

This is only coming on Android mobile. Something specific needs to be fixed or its the behaviour of MS teams?

[image]

---

works correctly in iOS MS Teams app:
[image]

Comment: showing some unusual working mean? Are you not able to see the drop down with proper inputs ? Could you please explain your scenario in more detail?

Comment: The list is appearing but very down, I'll share the pic how it works on iOS.

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue at our end. Could you please check with latest android version? Also could you please share the manifest for testing and teams version?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT, I was able to fix it on my side see the answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully replicated the issue in Android devices.
So, there was horizontal scrolling which was creating the problem on the Android devices but after removing that it worked. But it was very strange as this same thing didn’t give me an issue on iOS devices.

[image]